# Java thread: 'join' froze my program

Tags: java, multithreading, freeze

My program looked like this:

```
class Prog
 {
 BufferedImage offscreen;
 KindOfDatabase db;
 MyThread thread;

 class MyThread extends Thread
    {
    volatile boolean abort=false;
    long lastUpdated;
    public void run()
        {
        try
          {
          KindOfCursor c = db.iterator();
          while(c.getNext())
            {
            if(abort) break;
            //fill a histogram with the data,
            // calls SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait every 500ms to
            //do something with offscreen and update a JPanel
            }
          catch(Exception err)
            {
            err.printStackTrace();
            }
          finally
            {
            c.close();
            }
        }
    }

  void stopThread()
       {
       if(thread!=null)
          {
          thread.abort=true;
          thread.join();
          thread=null;
          }
       }
  void startThread()
      {
      stopThread();
      thread=new MyThread();
      thread.start();
      }
(....)
 }
```

1) The program worked well on my computer. But when I ran it threw a *'ssh -X remote.host.org '* connection, all was very slow and the program was frozen when thread.join() was invoked. I replaced 'join' by 'interrupt()' and the program was not anymore frozen. Why ? Should I fear that, when  interrupt() is called, the 'finally' statement closing the iterator was not invoked ?

2) should I use 'Thread.isInterrupted()' instead of my boolean 'abort' ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: my abort flag was labelled with volatile. Doesn't change the frozen state.

Comment: Your formatting style makes it really hard to quickly read the code :-(

Answer (score 7):

Thread.join is meant to "freeze" your thread!

When you call join, the current thread will pause until the thread it's joining on has exited.  In your case, this freeze is happening because the `MyThread` instance isn't exiting in a timely fashion.

One thing that might be biting you here - **you need to declare the abort variable as `volatile` for changes to be reliably seen by other threads**.  Since you aren't doing that, it's entirely possible for your MyThread to see a cached version of the abort variable where it's always true.  There's a short description of it [here](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=19&).

Edit: I missed your statement before about it working locally but not on a remote machine.  This is actually not that uncommon with concurrency-related race conditions, as they may or may not manifest depending on various factors such as the hardware setup, the load on the machine etc.  In this case for example, if your local machine only has one physical CPU/core then your erroneous code will *probably* run fine; there's only one CPU cache so the other thread is likely to "see" the main thread changing the `abort` flag, even though it's not explicitly marked as volatile.  Now move that to a multi-core machine, and if the threads get scheduled onto separate cores, they'll use separate caches and all of a sudden won't see changes to non-volatile, cached variables.

This is why it's very important to understand the ramifications of concurrency and exactly what's guaranteed, because failures do not manifest in a consistent manner.

**Update** reaction: if this still isn't working when abort is volatile, it sounds a lot like `MyThread` isn't checking the variable often enough.  Bear in mind that it will only "notice" the abort flag has been set directly after pulling another kind-of-row from your kind-of-cursor.  If it's possible that the processing of a single element with respect to the histogram can take a long time, then of course it won't see the flag during this time.

You probably just need to check the abort flag more often.  You say that you're calling `invokeAndWait` every 500ms; you ought to be checking your abort flag before each call of this so you have to wait at most 500ms for the thread to terminate!  Have a look through this part of your code and see if there are any inner loops that you can modify to look more like `while (... && !abort)`.

Another perpendicular approach to take is to start interrupting the thread as well.  SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait in particular is interruptable, so if you call `thread.interrupt()` in your `stopThread()` method, then the invokeAndWait call will terminate very quickly (by throwing an InterruptedException) rather than you having to wait until it completes normally before your code gets a chance to check the abort flag again.  This has the added benefit that if some other interruptible operation is taking a very long time to complete, it will also return straight away.  (In this case you'd probably want to explicitly catch the InterruptedException in your processing bit of code; you don't really need to do anything to handle it per se, just take it as a sign to wake up and check the flag again.  Read this excellent [Developerworks article](http://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236.html&ei=gE_MSuXpM9Ou4Qa_msT9BQ&sa=X&oi=spellmeleon_result&resnum=1&ct=result&usg=AFQjCNE-q40eAN-pwORlRjx7yeF5UFAqDg) for more information about handling InterruptedExceptions).

Finally, if you're still having problems then some good old-fashioned println debugging will help.  If you have `MyThread` print to the console (or possibly some log file) every time it checks the abort flag, you'll be able to see whether the problem is due to the MyThread itself "freezing"; as in this case it will never exit and the calling thread will never return from the join() call.  Moving the checking of the abort flag lower-down will probably help with this.

Comment: Thanks. Edited my code & added 'volatile'. This doesn't change this difference between the local and the remote program.

Comment: Thanks for this long answer. I can't connect to my remote server today. but I'll check your suggestion ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

You have shared data between two threads with no memory barriers. It's possible that if your main thread sets abort = true, it will set abort locally, but the other processor already has "false" in it's local cache for that field.

The volatile keyword is for exactly this purpose.

It may work on your machine because you have a single processor, but the remote machine may not.

Comment: interesting, I'll investigate this.

Comment: Thanks. Edited my code & added 'volatile'. This doesn't change this difference between the local and the remote program.

Answer (score 1):

What does your KindOfCursor's `c.next()` do? Is it blocking and waiting for more data? If so, interrupting it may have caused it to stop waiting and return quickly.

Comment: damnit, i was just typing that.

Comment: getting a thread dump would display where the system is hanging, and could determine whether `c.next()` is the culprit.  note that although `stopThread` sets `abort=true`, `if(abort)` needs to be executed in order to break.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to debug it? when you execute thread.join() command in main thread, it waits until thread finished. If your program is frozen after this command, probably thread not finished. The cause maybe you can not connect to DB, or you fetch data from DB (via remote host) too slowly. I think you should use log4j (or something can debug) to debug it.

Tip: you should not use variable boolean abort to control thread. It not safe if you apply in multithread enviroment. You try to replace by this code:

```
...in body thread
void run(){
    ...
    while(condition){
      if (interrupted()) 
          break;
    .....
}


...in body Prog class
void stopThread(){
    if(thread!=null)
    {
      thread.interrupt();
      thread.join();// i think you do not need this line, try it if you call interupt
      thread=null;
     }
}
```

Hope you resolve it soon.